# How to fix [karma-server]: Uncaught Exception

Tags: jasmine, angular-cli, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I have running Angular 9 application and I am running unit test in jasmine using the below command to run the tests and everything works fine:

```
ng test
```

But, when I am running unit test using watch=false, all the tests are passing, but I am getting "**UncaughtException**" at the end.

```
ng test --watch=false // using this command in SonarQube to generate UT report
```

[image]

SonarQube is not genearting UT report because of the above error.

**Is there any way to get the details of the error (log files or something) or debug the [karma-server]" UncaughtException error...?**

I am getting error from the below spec file:

**profile.component.spec.ts**

```
describe('Client.App.Advanced.ProfileComponent', () => {
    let component: ProfileComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ProfileComponent>;
    let httpMock: HttpTestingController;

    function mockHttp(data) {
        const mockReq = httpMock.expectOne((req) => true);
        mockReq.flush(data);
        httpMock.verify();
    }

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, RouterTestingModule],
            declarations: [ProfileComponent],
            providers: [ProfileToolHandlerService ]
        }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(fakeAsync(() => {
        httpMock = TestBed.inject<HttpTestingController>(HttpTestingController);
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ProfileComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
        // mock request for Login
        mockHttp(null);
        tick();
    }));

    it('shall create the component', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();
        expect(component).toBeDefined();
    });
}
```

Comment: You may find [this](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/3295) interesting. This seems like a random thing with the karma runner. I see it consistently with some of my repos. Never did get fixed.

Comment: for me, this is happening after adding profile spec file. If I comment this file and run all other test, I don't get the [karma-error]: Uncaught exception